# Why does CMD not recognize the javadoc command?

Tags: java, installation

I installed JDK on windows 10, 64bit, followed the documentation instructions.. CMD does not recognize javadoc command. What I tried:
-copied the path of the "bin" folder from Java and in cmd I wrote the command:

```
set path = "full_path_to_java_sdk_bin_folder"
```

I saw this on youtube and it worked for the guy, my cmd still did not recognize javadoc command  
-I set the PATH in system variables from control panel->system->advanced->environment variables and made sure that there are is no other bin folder...
Didn't find any other tips online...

Comment: First, `set "JAVA_HOME=full_path_to_jdk"` then `set "PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%"` - my quotes are correct for Windows on the CMD line.

Comment: to jdk or to jdk/bin?

Comment: TO JDK. The second command adds bin. You don't want JDK\bin\bin.

Comment: thank you so much!!! If you want, post it as an answer so I can rate it <3. Saved me some headaches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual approach for Java development is to set a `JAVA_HOME` environment variable, and use that to update the `PATH` (for one thing, it makes it much easier to support multiple versions of Java). Also of note is that Windows puts the quotes oddly on the command line (oddly compared to every other platform that is) and if your path contains spaces you need to quote it correctly. Like,

```
set "JAVA_HOME=<full_path_to_jdk>"
set "PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%"
```